# Create a new page in asp.net on button click

Tags: asp.net, html, file, new-operator

I'm trying to create a portfolio website where students can log in, choose from a selection of templates and then edit the content.

The users page is already set up but contains no html or asp.net.
I want to have it so that when the user selects the template and clicks the button, the code from that template is then written into their page.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: You might also want to consider a Content Management System (CMS) - there are plenty of .Net ones that are open source and/or free - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954764/good-net-based-cms

Answer (score 1):

Creating physical pages is not a good idea.

What you rather can do is to have your "pages" in the database and expose them through a url facade built on url rewriting.

A simplest example would be - you have a table, `PAGES` with `Name` and `Body`. Pages can be accessed with `ShowPage.aspx?page=PageName`. However, a facade exposes them as `Pages/PageName.aspx` which is internally rewritten into the `ShowPage.aspx?page=PageName`.

It doesn't really matter if you code agains WebForms or MVC, the general idea remains the same.

Comment: But how would I get the write the html/asp from the selected template so that the users personal page then has that code as well?

Comment: Tons of options. Dynamic pages can be created from manually crafted HTML, you can even expose a web HTML editor or you can dynamically create data from other tables.

Comment: How would I do it using a table in a database?